Next.js suspense server-side doesn't work
I'm encountering an issue with Next.js 14. I want to load an Async component in the Page component. In the  component, I simulate a server delay of 5 seconds. However, what happens is that I end up waiting for 5 seconds for the entire page to load, not just the  component
Page component: app/page.tsx
import { Suspense } from "react";
import ItemList from "./ItemList";

export default async function Page() {
  return (
    <main>
      Hello Sample Page!
      <div>
        <Suspense fallback={"Loading..."}>
          <ItemList />
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}

ItemList component: app/ItemList.tsx
export default async function ItemList() {

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))

  const items = [
    { id: "test-1", name: "chocolate" },
    { id: "test-2", name: "rice ball" },
  ]

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item =>
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.name}
        </li>
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}


Can I get some guidance on how to preload the Page and then load the  afterward? Preferably without resorting to the client-side

I tried reproducing and it's working properly, i don't know what's in your application that's causing the error, react suspense is supposed to work both client-side and server-side

I've tried everything, and it doesn't work. I'm starting to think I might have some incorrect settings, but nothing seems wrong...

When i tried reproducing, the component was the only thing that rendered the suspense component, other components weren't affected by the suspense.

My goal is to achieve the behavior shown at the 20-minute mark of the video https://youtu.be/vwSlYG7hFk0?si=1YkCtMkfJIoHr0PO

Yeah, in the video the guy had no problem rendering suspense, have you checked if your dependencies's versions are by any chance outdated or old?

Yes, all dependencies are up to date... :(

Sorry mate, I really don't know, maybe i can help if you share a repository or a codesandbox link.

Thanks anyway, you're very kind! Maybe tomorrow, it's 2 AM here, and I need to sleep! Ahahah
